# How to prevent unauthorized access to media streams

Tags: .net, silverlight, video-streaming, cdn

I have a client who is using Siverlight media streaming and wants to start charging for access to certain videos (pay-per-view). Many of those videos with be live-streamed.

I am looking for a solution to restrict the media streams to only the clients who have paid.

As it stands I think each video resource is located at fixed URL - if you know the URL you can watch the stream. Obviously they dont want that. To complicate it further the URL is hosted on a CDN.

There are a few products like IIS Media Services that let you restrict access to "WebPlaylists" but it does not mention about it might work with a CDN.

Are there any of the shelf solutions or are we looking at something custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look to use PlayReady DRM which is one of the options with Silverlight.
The easiest way to do this is by working with an PlayReady service provider:
http://www.microsoft.com/PlayReady/Licensing/engageprovider.mspx

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting although Im suspicious it might be overkill. I guess I wasnt considering DRM. But without DRM I suppose its pretty easy to restream/copy/save the content even if everyone does have a unique URL